# Buffalo Firewall denying connection

Tags: buffalo-router

I have a WHR-HP-GN Buffalo wireless router and for some reason I keep on seeing the following when I goto Diagnostic -> Logs
Type,Log Content
FIREWALL,TCP connection denied from 192.168.20.3:80 to 192.168.40.2:54786 (br0)

Can someone let me know why this is the case?  192.168.40.2 is my PC and 192.168.20.3 is my printer.  I used to be able to browse to the printer's webpage from my PC but for some reason it stopped working and when I investigated I found the above log entry.  However I am unable to find where there may be a setting to restrict this traffic.

My PC has the following settings:
192.168.40.2
255.255.255.0

My printer is sitting in a different subnet with following settings:
192.168.20.3
255.255.255.0

Comment: Do you have two distinct LANs with different ranges? Or do you have one huge LAN that includes all the way from 192.168.20.x to 192.168.40.x?

Comment: Just to clarify David's question if you aren't familiar with this stuff:  what does the subnet mask say on your PC and your router?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Just updated my post with the details.